# Boundary condition for partial reflection

Tags: waves, reflection, boundary-conditions, differential-equations

I want to solve a wave equation for the wave $\psi(x,t)$.
One boundary is moving, therefore I impose the velocity

$$v(x=0)=v_a\cos(\omega t)$$

the other boundary is fixed, but reflecting. If the reflection is total the proper boundary condition is

$$ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}\bigg|_{x=L}=0 $$

Which is the right boundary condition if the reflection is partial? Therefore, my boundary has a reflection coefficient $R$ and an absorbing coefficient $A$ (no transmission), so that $R+A=1$.

Comment: Note that simply knowing $R$ is not sufficient to determine the boundary conditions.   For example, the reflection coefficient for a wave on a string is $R = 1$ both when the end is fixed ($\phi = 0$ at $x = L$) and when the end is free ($\partial \phi/\partial x = 0$ at $x = L$.)  So there is not likely to be a unique answer to your question unless you add more information.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I have specified in my question that the reflecting end is fixed. Is that not enough? Which other informations should I add?

Comment: Very closely related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/252466/can-you-have-a-problem-with-a-dirichlet-boundary-condition-but-with-waves-that-r https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/217063/what-boundary-conditions-in-a-wave-simulation-would-avoid-reflections

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider a boundary condition of the form
$$
\alpha \psi + \beta \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} + \gamma \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} =0
$$
on the boundary, where $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ are real coefficients.  Standard Dirichlet boundary conditions correspond to $\beta = \gamma = 0, \alpha \neq 0$, while Neumann boundary conditions correspond to $\alpha = \gamma = 0, \beta \neq 0$.

If we impose this condition at $x = 0$ for an incoming wave of the form $\psi(x,t) = e^{i(kx - \omega t)}$, then the wave solution for $\psi$ will be
$$
\psi(x,t) = e^{i(kx - \omega t)} + A e^{i(-kx - \omega t)}
$$
where $A$ is the (complex) amplitude of the reflected wave.  Some algebra then reveals that we must have
$$
A = \frac{i (k \beta - \omega \gamma) + \alpha}{i (k \beta + \omega \gamma) - \alpha},
$$
and so
$$
R = |A|^2 = \frac{(k \beta - \omega \gamma)^2 + \alpha^2}{(k \beta + \omega \gamma)^2 + \alpha^2}.
$$
By appropriate choices of $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$, one can "tune" the reflection coefficient to be anywhere between 0 and 1.

A few notes on this expression:

- Even if the medium is non-dispersive (i.e., the speed of propagation is independent of frequency), the reflection coefficient will only be frequency-independent if either (a) $\beta = \gamma = 0$, or (b) $\alpha = 0$.  And if the reflection coefficient is frequency-dependent, this means that a pulse sent towards the wall will not be reflected with the same shape.  If you want pulses to retain their shape on reflection, you need one of the above conditions.
- For a given value of $R$, the coefficients $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ are not uniquely determined.  This is for two reasons.  First, we can always divide or multiply all three coefficients by the same number to get the same boundary condition;  you can always use this freedom to set one (non-zero) coefficient equal to 1 if you like. Second, the reflection coefficient alone doesn't tell you everything about the reflected wave;  the reflected wave can also be phase-shifted.
- If $\gamma = 0$, we have $R = 1$ identically.  This makes some sense;  in such a case, the equations have time-reversal symmetry, whereas absorption involves an inherent "arrow of time".

Comment: Thank you for you very interesting and useful answer, but I think my question is not fully solved. You are telling me that any combination of $\alpha, \, \beta, \, \gamma$ will give me a finite $R$. Still, it is not clear to me which one of these three parameters I should choose to be $\neq 0$ to create a model of a fixed reflecting wall and why.

Comment: @AlessandroZunino:  That's because for any particular value of $R$, there's more than one set of coefficients that yields it.  I've edited my answer to explain this further.