# Transparent Boundary Conditions 1D Klein Gordon

Tags: boundary-conditions, klein-gordon-equation

The wave equation is an example of an equation for which there are simple transparent boundary conditions. We can factorize the wave operator
$$\partial_t^2 -\partial_x^2 = (\partial_t - \partial_x)(\partial_t + \partial_x)\,.$$
The physical interpretation of this operator is that each factor is responsible for propagation right and left respectively. Then, to implement transparent boundary conditions on the right boundary, we can simply demand that nothing propagates left:
$$(\partial_t + \partial_x)\psi|_{x = L} = 0\,,$$
where the domain extends in $x$ from $-L$ to $L$.

Now, enter the Klein Gordon operator.
$$\partial_t^2 -\partial_x^2 + 1\,.$$
Apparently no such factorization exists... But certainly there is a way to implement transparent boundary conditions?

Comment: Related answers on deriving non-reflecting boundary conditions: [BCs in elastic media](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/217063/what-boundary-conditions-in-a-wave-simulation-would-avoid-reflections/217068#217068), [BCs in E&M](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/252466/can-you-have-a-problem-with-a-dirichlet-boundary-condition-but-with-waves-that-r/252468#252468). I don't have experience with this specific equation to help in detail, but any guidance I would give would be the same as on those other answers...

Comment: You can still factorize the Klein Gordon operator, you just need to introduce square roots of the differential operators. This is more clear if you do a Fourier transform. The Klein Gordon equation has left and right propagating solutions, as long as the frequency is higher than $1$.