# Wave simulation without reflection on the boundaries

Tags: waves, computational-physics, simulations, boundary-conditions

I would like to numerically simulate a wave (let's say in a string) with different boundary conditions:

1. Fixed endpoints
2. Periodic
3. Boundless

$\varphi(x, t)$ is the value of the wave (vertical position of the string) at pixel $x$ captured by a 1-D array `phi`. For fixed endpoints, I simply pad my array with a zero on the left and one on the right (for numerical differentiation purposes). For the periodic boundary, I pad the left side with the last element (`phi[-1]` in Python syntax) and I pad the right side with the first element (`phi[+1]`).

How do I handle the boundless case so a pulse would just travel without reflection similar to the figure below? What is the common term for this type of boundary? (I do not want to sufficiently increase the number of pixels to solve this problem).

[image: Wave propagation without reflection]

Comment: What you ask for is called PML for perfectly matched layer, but I never succeeded to implementit it in my case because I have to accommodate evanescent waves and standard methods fail in such case.

Comment: @lemon It's not the Neumann condition -- that will also generate a wave reflection. See the "soft boundary condition" on [this page](https://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/demos/reflect/reflect.html)

Comment: Side note @Miladiouss -- did you take this image from [this website](https://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/demos/reflect/reflect.html)? Because the author explicitly states the images can't be used other places without permission. If so, please find another source that has a usable license.

Comment: @tpg2114, I'll replace the image.

Comment: Can't you just compute the movement of the last element as if it were connected to another one, without computing the movement of this next element ? I assume you are solving the wave equation in time domain ?

Comment: @Miladiouss What numerical method do you use?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about programming not physics.

Comment: @tpg2114, I have generated my own photo.

Comment: @JonCuster, if I post this in a programming forum, they would say it is physics and if I post it here you would say it is programming. I think it is physics because my question is about boundary condition of differential equations. I am not asking a programming question.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, I'm writing a simple python code, no underlying platform. I am calling the approach "numerical method" since I'm solving PDE using pixels and time evolving them. I hope that clears it.

Comment: @David, that's what I thought, but what is $\phi$ and $\dot{\phi}$ for that last element?

Comment: @tpg2114, I thought this was a duplicate of the linked question, but the answer doesn't apply. Though AlexTrounev's answer is not very clear, it works. See my comments under his answer.

Comment: @Miladiouss From my point of view, the answer is very clear. But I will add a couple more lines.

Answer (score 1):

One picture is worth 1000 words. Consider a simple example. For the wave equation $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$, initial and boundary conditions are given:

$u(0,x)=0,u_t(0,x)=0,u(t,0)=f(t),u_t(t,2)+u_x(t,2)=0$

$f(t)=0,t\le 0.01$ or $t\ge1.01$, $f(t)=\sin {t}, 0.01<t<1.01$

To solve this problem we use Method Of Lines. The solution on a coarse grid is shown in the animation.

[image: fig1]

We give an explanation.
We write the wave equation in the form

$v=u_t+u_x, v_t-v_x=0$

The general solution of the first equation for $v=0$ is $u=f(x-t)$ - wave moving to the right.The general solution of the second equation is $v=g(x+t)$ -wave moving to the left. So that the wave does not reflect from the right border, the condition should be set on the right border $v=u_t+u_x=0$.

How to implement this conditions in the numerical method? The answer depends on the method.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. Also, please investigate the `cases` environment in LaTeX.

Comment: @KyleKanos You do not see that this is a wave without reflection or do not understand the boundary conditions for a wave without reflection?

Comment: No, I don't see how your contrived example gives a general solution to the issue OP has.

Comment: @KyleKanos This example exactly matches what Miladiouss asks.

Comment: I disagree. You show an animation that shows an outflow boundary, but don't mention how it's implemented (which is what OP is asking for).

Comment: @KyleKanos I added a few words to my answer.

Comment: Your answer is not very clear, however, I tried $u_t = -u_x$ before updating in each step and I got the desired result. Thank you! I would accept your answer if you can elaborate on that. Even though nice, I also don't think the animation is necessary.

Comment: FYI, here is how I coded it: `phiDot[-1] = -(phi[-1] - phi[-2])`

Comment: @Miladiouss On which grid did you get the solution?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, I don't understand the question. What do you mean by which grid?
can you explain why $v=0$ on the boundary?

Comment: What is the name of this boundary condition?

Comment: @Miladiouss $v$ is wave moving to the left. If we put $v = 0$ on the right border, this means that there are no reflected waves moving to the left.

Comment: It is called Nonreflecting boundary conditions

Comment: Ok, now that you explained what $v$ is, it makes more sense. 
I tried editing your question, but it was rejected in the review process.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for *outflow* boundary conditions. The constraint in this case is that the derivative is constant:
$$
\frac {\partial u}{\partial n}=0
$$
where $n$ is the normal direction of the surface (e.g., $x$). This is also probably more commonly known as the *Neumann boundary condition*.

In numerical language, this would be akin to using `phi[N]=phi[N-1]`.

Comment: The Neumann condition is reflective for this case (and for compressible Navier-Stokes as well -- low-Mach preconditioning relaxes the reflectivity though). A wave will move back into the domain, not perfectly exit the domain as desired.

Comment: You would know more than I on that; all the CFD I worked on was "simple" MHD & never needed to worry about BCs (bc I kept the domain large enough to never worry about it).

Comment: The curse of working on internal flows... boundary conditions are a major PITA.

Comment: This seems to reflect as well. Unless I'm doing something wrong. I just set `phi[-1] = phi[-2]` before updating for each step.

Comment: @Miladiouss I imagine it depends on your stencil also. Could need to be `phi[N]=2*phi[N-1]-phi[N-2]`, for example, if you have higher orders.

Comment: I figured it out (with everyone's help). See my comments on AlexTrounev's answer.

Comment: @Miladiouss This BC will always reflect for this application. The page you originally got your figure from (and that I linked to in the comments on your question) shows that too.

Comment: @KyleKanos I also use zero Neumann boundary condition for incompressible viscous flows, but for compressible flow this gives reflected waves as tpg2114 indicated.